# How can I visit Antarctica?

Tags: extreme-tourism, antarctica

A year ago I was reading some magazine, and found out that there is availability to get a trip to Antarctica.
Unfortunately, there was no info about how I could get there.
Do you know anything about it? Best way to get there, best route, maybe some feedback?

Comment: Keep in mind that what is the "best" way is a bit subjective since what's best for one person is not what's best for everybody. That said Antarctica has much fewer options than most destinations.

Comment: @hippietrail Removed the word "best"

Comment: @VMAtm: Now it asks for a list rather than a subjective opinion (-:

Comment: @hippietrail Don't know how to rephrase that. Any ideas? For now I chose the "safiest".

Comment: I think since the mods are not playing strict with this question that's actually the right thing to do in this case because Antarctica has a special paucity of options. Maybe just "how to visit" is fine for this destination.

Comment: And here is the mods :) Thank you, @Michael Pryor

Comment: @VMAtm This is a great question. The other ones...hmmm.. but this one is right on the money ;)

Comment: You may be interested in watching: "Encounters at the end of the world" a documentary by Werner Herzog.

Comment: Please don't. We can't afford to ruin this Earthly by tourism. http://youtu.be/dH573B1bkHI

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are a few ways to visit Antarctica. Remember that **nothing is ever guaranteed** and it's quite possible with weather that you might not make it there.

**Cruises:**
Larger cruises often will get you close but not to the land. You'll have the comforts of cruising. These big ships may be regulated soon. Smaller ships will often let you get right onto land. Costs start at least $5k (for the ultra cheap).

**Tailored Expeditions:**
Many companies run specialty expeditions which let you visit Antarctica exactly how you want. Prices are extremely high for this.

**Airborne:**
You get to fly over Antarctica. This is the more ecological way to see it but doesn't have the same experience as actually walking on it. This is also the cheapest option.

Answer (score 33):

Almost all tourist methods leave from [Ushuia, in Argentina](http://maps.google.ru/maps?q=Ushuaia,%20Argentina&hl=ru&t=h&z=14).  You could get work on a boat, book a cruise, or take a tour with GAP Adventures, among others. However, there is almost NO cheap option.

However, if you're after a cheaper option and have some time to spare, arrive in November. It's the start of the season and many of the boats aren't full.  As such, they often offer 50% off the prices of trips to Antarctica.  It's still expensive, but a massive saving!

November is also a good time to visit the area, with [El Calafate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Calafate) up north being a gateway to the glaciers, mountains and national parks. [Perito Moreno glacier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perito_Moreno_Glacier) **has to be seen to be believed**!

Answer (score 33):

Work in Antarctica:

[USA vacancies](http://www.icecube.wisc.edu/jobs):

> Degree Requirements
>   M.S. in Physics, Electrical Engineering, Computer Science or related field is required. B.S. in Physics, Electrical Engineering, Computer Science, or related field and substantial (equivalent to a masters degree) experience will be considered.

[Russian vacancies](http://antarctic-2010.livejournal.com/115153.html) (from [here](http://www.aari.nw.ru/dept/kadry/rae.html)):

- Meteorologist-aktinometrist
- Geophysicist - ionosphere expert, riometrist, magnetologist
- Aerologist and Radiolocator-technician
- System administrator, developer
- Specialist on environmental protection equipment
- Hydrologist
- Radio Engineer (modern radio communication expert)
- Surgeon or anesthesiologist
- Mechanic-technician
- "Pisten bully Polar-300" driver, etc
- Electric and gas welder-driver
- Cook

Comment: Using computers to help detect neutrinos in Antarctica? That would be the coolest job ever! (Pun intended)

Comment: @mouviciel Updated the answer

Comment: If your "visit" can last 6 months (or whatever one shift takes).

Answer (score 21):

Another approach you can take involves getting seasonal work as an unskilled laborer in support of one of the governments doing research there. In particular I think Great Britain, the United States, Australia, and Russia have big Antarctic programs and thus employ a lot of civilians.
If you're looking for a job at one of the American stations, almost all hiring is done through [Raytheon](http://www.rayjobs.com/index.cfm?NavID=25)

Comment: I was told the easiest such job to get is cook. I was told this by a guy who worked as a cook in Antarctica. Not sure which country though I met him in Canada. Of course you have to be able to cook at least as well as a prison cook I assume (-:

Comment: New Zealand too (Scott Base)

Answer (score 13):

I believe most of the most popular route is by cruise ship and the most common departure port is [Ushuaia, Argentina](http://maps.google.ru/maps?q=Ushuaia,%20Argentina&hl=ru&t=h&z=14).

Answer (score 11):

Become a researcher in an Earth/Planetary Science department or in a lab that studies the physics of ice. The department I'm in at Brown University does send expeditions to study the dry ice valleys in Antarctica (to study parallels with Martian climate).

Alternatively, do research on penguins (though there are not many penguin researchers in the world).

E.g. the [University of Washington Polar Science Center](http://psc.apl.washington.edu/)