# 100 Years Since South Pole Expedition - How to reach it as a tourist?

Tags: adventure, events, antarctica

[It's been 100 years](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/travelnews/2011/11/111214-amundsen-scott-norway-antarctica-explorers-science-history-south-pole-anniversary/) since humans first reached the South Pole.

According to the [International Association of Antarctica Tour Operators](http://iaato.org/), about 30,000 people visit the continent of Antarctica annually.  However, only a fraction make it to the pole.

Is there a "frugal traveller" means of reaching the South Pole?  What options exist?  Do you need a team or can you join a group tour?  How much time needs to be allocated for a round-trip there?

Comment: That's why I saw two documentary movies about it yesterday :D

Comment: [related question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6/antarctica-way-to-visit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some expeditions that you can join as a single person. Most of these take place during November, December, January and February ([example](http://www.arctic-world.com/index.php?option=com_viajes&view=detalle&id=18&a=&Itemid=64)). Just start this December. As you can see, it is a relatively short tour because you fly to 89° longitude. But nevertheless, it takes approximately three weeks.